# Trying to show $\mathrm{tr}(T|_{w^\perp})=\mathrm{tr}(U)$ for linear operators $T,U$

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, inner-products

I'm working the following proposition.

> **Proposition.** Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ and let $w$ be a unit vector in $V$. Define $U:V\to V$ by
> $$U(x)=T(x)-\langle x,w\rangle T(w).$$
> If $T$ takes $w^\perp$ to $w^\perp$, then
> $$\mathrm{tr}(T|_{w^\perp})=\mathrm{tr}(U).$$

The source of this proposition does not say much about its notation, so let us assume for the moment that $w^\perp$ represents $\{w\}^\perp$, the orthogonal complement of the set $\{w\}$ relative to the given inner product. Another problem is about the statement that $T$ takes $w^\perp$ to $w^\perp$, which I suppose means that $T(w^\perp)=w^\perp$.

My attempt begins by selecting an ordered basis $\beta$ for $V$, because the trace of a linear operator $N$ is defined as the trace of its matrix in $\beta$, which we denote by $[N]_\beta$. Now I was wondering how I can approach $\mathrm{tr}(T|_{w^\perp})$. It looks like I have to interpret the restriction $T|_{w^\perp}$ as $T|_{w^\perp}:w^\perp\to w^\perp$ if I want its trace to be well defined. Then, how do I find an ordered basis for the subspace $w^\perp$ in order to evaluate the trace? What I know for the time being is that intuitively we can see $w^\perp$ as a plane perpendicular to $w$.

Thank you.

**Edit.** Sorry, I have to correct a misconception. If $T$ takes $w^\perp$ to $w^\perp$, then we had better interpret it as $T(w^\perp)\subseteq w^\perp$ because we didn't say "onto".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U(cw)=T(cw)-\langle cw,w\rangle T(w)=0$ so $U$ is $0$ on $span \{w\}$. Also, note that $T|_{w^\perp}=U|_{w^\perp}$.

Hence, $\mathrm{tr}(T|_{w^\perp})=\mathrm{tr}(U|_{w^\perp})=\mathrm{tr}(U)$. The last equality follows from the fact that $V=span \{w\}\oplus w^{\perp}$.

Comment: May I ask you a beginner question? Did you get $T|_{w^\perp}=U|_{w^\perp}$ by showing $T=U$ on $w^\perp$, which also gets you the fact that $U$ takes $w^\perp$ to $w^\perp$? Thank you.

Comment: I get that from the fact that $ \langle x, w \rangle=0$ if $x \in w^{\perp}$.

Comment: Yes, I did the same to get the result.

Comment: Can I ask one last question? I just verified the direct sum. It's perfectly true, but how does it help us equate the trace of $U$ with the trace of its restriction? Thank you.

Comment: If $V=M\oplus M^{\perp}$ then $tr (U)=tr (U|_M)+tr (U|_{M^{\perp}})$

Comment: I just proved $(\mathrm{span}\{w\})^\perp=w^\perp$, so I can see $$V=\mathrm{span}\{w\}\oplus(\mathrm{span}\{w\})^\perp=\mathrm{span}\{w\}\oplus w^\perp.$$

Comment: I'm very sorry. Is $\mathrm{tr}(U)=\mathrm{tr}(U|_M)+\mathrm{tr}(U|_{M^\perp})$ a universal property? I'm not sure about it although I just proved $\mathrm{tr}(U)=\mathrm{tr}(U|_{\mathrm{span}\{w\}})+\mathrm{tr}(U|_{w^\perp})$.

Comment: The decompostion we have is not just an algebraic direct sum. It is an orthogonal direct sum. That is why trace splits into two parts.